# unbale to create virtual device server returned HTTP status code 0

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtual, genymotion

when want add virtual device in genymotion it become for me :

```
Unable to create the virtual device 
Server returned HTTP status code 0
```

[image]

research about this is stack over flow and try so many ways but did not work